# Can every JSON serializable Java object be represented as a Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a bunch of Java objects that are being serialized with Jackson. All of the serialized types look something like this:

```
class MySampleClass {
    @JsonProperty("propName1")
    private MyCustomType propName1;

    @JsonProperty("propName2")
    private MyOtherCustomType propName2;

    @JsonCreator
    public MySampleClass(@JsonProperty("propName1") MyCustomType propName1, @JsonProperty("propName2") MyOtherCustomType propName2) {
        this.propName1 = propName1;
        this.propName2 = propName2;
    }
}
```

Is there any case where converting instances of this class to a `Map<String, Object>` and then converting the map to JSON will not be desearializable back into the original Java object?

Comment: It depends on the framework/logic we are using to convert to and from `Map`. If it uses `toString()` while serializing then the resultant output may not be the same as original json.

Comment: Jackson is being used to serialize the map / object.

Comment: In that case, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'll do it, unless you are receiving an array of these objects.  If that's the case, then you can use `MySampleClass[]`.

JSON is defined in RFC 7159.  From here:

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
>   pairs, **where a name is a string** and a value is a string, number,
>   boolean, null, object, or array.

(emphasis mine)

So, a JSON object must have Strings as keys, and values can be one of a handful of Object types.

Comment: As state in my original question, the Java objects and `Map<String, Object>` are identical. However, if the fields or class have additional Jackson annotations, such as `@JsonSerialize(using = WhateverSerializer.class)` then they are not equivalent.